# How to use new theme in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming, ubuntu-12.04

I'm new to WordPress. I read that, in order to use a new theme, I need to download it and save it in wp-content/themes. I did that, and I see the new theme on

```
 http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php
```

but when I preview it, there is nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: Did you unzip the theme file into that folder or just copy the zip file into there themes folder?

Comment: I unzipped it in Downloads and copied the unzipped folder into themes folder

Answer (score 0):

First, your theme directory should be like this: `wp_root/wp-content/themes/your-theme` . And all themes have index.php and style.css

Comment: This is in /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vantage and /usr/shared/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vantage:
404.php 
footer.php 
index.php  
page.php  
slider
archive.php   
functions.php  
js  
parts  
style.css
comments.php  
header.php  
languages  
README.md  
style.less
content-page.php    
home-panels.php  
less screenshot.png  
templates
content.php  
icons license.txt  
searchform.php  tour
content-single.php  
image.php  
loop.php  
search.php      
upgrade
extras  
images   
loops  
sidebar.php
fontawesome   
inc   
no-results.php  
single.php

Comment: try this theme different wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

It might be problem in theme code. you may contact theme provider.